# How to make the Y-Axis not touch the X-Axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to move the Y-Axis a bit higher and not intersect with the X-Axis.. This is how it currently looks..

[image]

This is how I want it to look like:

[image]

This is the code I have written for that.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig = matplotlib.pyplot.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(6.0,3.0)

t = 100

kde = gaussian_kde(hurry)
dist_space_hurry = linspace( min(hurry), max(hurry), t )
ax.plot( dist_space_hurry, kde(dist_space_hurry), color='r', label='Hurry-up', linewidth=1.5)

kde_faban = gaussian_kde(faban_data)
faban_dist_space = linspace( min(faban_data), max(faban_data), t )
ax.plot( faban_dist_space, kde_faban(faban_dist_space) , color='g', label = 'Faban', linewidth=2)

ax.legend(loc='upper center', ncol=1, framealpha=0, bbox_to_anchor=(0.7, .95), fancybox=True)#, fontsize=8)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
```

Comment: @RoryDaulton: The included graphic is what is happening right now.. The new graphic is how i want it to look like.

Comment: Your edit has made things more clear--good job. I don't know matplotlib well enough to answer your question, unfortunately.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Based on the look of the plots included in this question, it looks like tandem might be using version 1.5 or earlier.

Comment: That is correct. i'm using 1.3.1.

Comment: You may want to consider upgrading, as that is a very old version.  In the meantime, you can manually set the lower axis limit with `ax.axis(ymin=y)`, where `y` is the desired coordinate, which you can choose to be some value slightly less than zero.